# ip command in macOS

Tags: macos, docker

I want to run my command in couchbase docker container but it says that 
bash: ip: commant not found

My command is :

```
ip=$(ip -o route get to 8.8.8.8 | sed -n 's/.*src \([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/p')
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: That seems like an extremely detailed command...what are you actually trying to find out with it?

Comment: Actually, I dont know. I need to do configuration for my database. There is a doc for that and I just want to use. However, I am new on Linux or Mac terminals.

Comment: Maybe if you showed the output of `ip -o route get to 8.8.8.8` on some system where it works, someone could say how to get that info on a Mac..

Answer (score 1):

brew install iproute2mac Hope it helps check this question too. [Other stack question](https://superuser.com/questions/687310/ip-command-in-mac-os-x-terminal)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I can't even install homebrew to my docker container.. Any idea?